# jsp getting post parameters and posting them to another jsp with new values

Tags: jsp, post

i am new to jsp and an need to write a jsp getting post parameters for further processing.
The parameters values must be set to a new value and they must be sent to another jsp with POST.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: You can use `request.getParameter("parametername")`for accessing parameters.In the similay fashion,before forwarding your request to any other jsp,you can set them like `request.setParamter("key","value")`

Comment: @Prince, the question states that POST will be used not a forward.  user3232312 How are you POSTing? Are you using a HttpURLConnection object?

Comment: as far as i know there is no setParameter only getParameter? i have no idea how to post the new values. i am opened to any suggestion

Comment: You could use "Prince Mani Gupta"'s idea of forwarding, but instead of setting  new values of parameters, you could use request.setAttribute("myKey", value);   In the second JSP use String value = (String)request.getAttribute("myKey");  or <%= request.getAttribute("myKey")> or simply ${myKey}

Comment: the point is that i can not modify the second jsp. so i don't know if the set/getAttribute will do the trick.i do only know that the second jsp is waiting for post parameters.

Comment: In that case, you could use a HttpURLConnection object in the first JSP to send a post request with the parameters to the second JSP. The first JSP would have to wait for the response from the second JSP and send it to the client as it's response.

Comment: How does second JSP differentiate a GET from a POST?

Comment: i am too new at jsp to implement your idea. but i guess that's the right way to do what i need to do.perhaps you have a piece of code to put me in the track. thanks for your help.

Comment: How does second JSP differentiate a GET from a POST?

Answer (score 0):

Here is demonstration code. It uses a quick and dirty scriptlet.

```
<%@ page import="java.net.*,java.io.*" %>
 <%
  URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/target.jsp");
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  conn.setDoInput(true);
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
  OutputStream connOut = conn.getOutputStream();
  connOut.write("a=111&b=222".getBytes()); //you might need URLEncoder
  connOut.flush();
  connOut.close();
  if(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == conn.getResponseCode()){
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()), 8192);
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     String line = "";
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
             sb.append(line);
    }
        in.close(); 
        out.print(sb.toString());
  }else out.print("Response code is " + conn.getResponseCode());
%>
```

here is target.jsp

```
hello from target.jsp a is ${param.a} and b is ${param.b} 
  and request method is  ${pageContext.request.method}
```